# Смена цвета кнопки при зажатии [Java]

Tags: java, button, color, listener, mouse-event

Смоделируем ситуацию: есть кнопка (например, зеленого цвета), при наведении должен измениться цвет фона на синий, а при зажатии - на красный. Но при реализации через интерфейс MouseListener она меняет свой цвет на совершенно другой. Не знаю, связано это с неправильной реализацией или с особенностями Windows... Помогите разобраться новичку.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;    

public class Test extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    JButton button = new JButton("Test button");

    public Test() {
        super("Test window");
        setSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        button.addMouseListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(button);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        button.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Так выглядит кнопка в обычном состоянии:

[image: Так выглядит кнопка в обычном состоянии]

Кнопка при наведении на нее курсора:

[image: Кнопка при наведении на нее курсора]

Кнопка при зажатии на ней ЛКМ:

[image: Кнопка при зажатии на ней ЛКМ]

Кнопка при зажатии на ней ПКМ:

[image: Кнопка при зажатии на ней ПКМ]

Как видно, при зажатии ПКМ все работает отлично, но при ЛКМ - нет.

Comment: Зачем нажимать разным кнопками?

Comment: @RomanC Не понял вопрос. В примере одна кнопка. Все методы слушателя переопределены для нее / одной кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Долго искал, но в итоге нашел кое-какое решение.

Проблема была вызвана тем, что у `JButton` есть своя область содержимого, которую система, при нажатии кнопки, автоматически заполнит своим внутренним выбранным цветом.

В интернете знатоки советуют никогда не использовать [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listdatalistener.html) для [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), а использовать [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) или [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html). Но это не особо помогло, при нажатии цвет все равно был не тем что надо.

Лучшим решением для меня было расширить `JButton`, чтобы создать свою собственную кнопку, отключить заполнение области содержимого и нарисовать свой фон.

Вот новый код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public static final Color DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    public static final Color ROLLOVER_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    public static final Color PRESSED_COLOR = Color.RED;

    JButton button = new MyButton("Test button");

    public Test() {
        super("Test window");
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        button.setFocusable(false);
        getContentPane().add(button);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyButton extends JButton {
    MyButton() {
        this(null);
    }

    MyButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Test.DEFAULT_COLOR);
        if (getModel().isRollover()) {
            g.setColor(Test.ROLLOVER_COLOR);
        }
        if (getModel().isPressed()) {
            g.setColor(Test.PRESSED_COLOR);
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Немного пояснений:

`JButton button = new MyButton("Test button");` - тут мы создаем собственным конструктором новую кнопку. Отличие в том, что он отключает заполнение области содержимого - `super.setContentAreaFilled(false);`

В переопределенном методе `paint()` мы перерисовываем фон кнопки.

`isRollover()` - метод [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html); указывает, что мышь находится над кнопкой.

`isPressed()` -  указывает, нажата ли кнопка.

*Примечание: я использовал структуру `if {...} if {...}`, так как `if {...} else if {...}` отказывалась работать.*